# Locate a cell with a particular value from a given range and find its corresponding value from topmost row and first column

Tags: vba, find, match, lookup

I am new to coding and a learner by myself. I am seriously stuck in one place on a small experimental project I am working on. Please help me on this.

[Base Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaUmu.jpg)

Here is what I intend to do.
Refer to the pic attached - From the given table, I want to locate a cell with a particular value (say, 0.1314). Then I want to find and add the values from corresponding cells in topmost row and first column (i.e, -1.1 + 0.2).

I have tried with Find, Match and Lookup commands but always getting some error.

Please suggest what is the appropriate command prompt for this. Also can anyone help me with the code?

Thanks
Shreya

Comment: What error you are getting ? Post what you've tried.

Comment: `Find()` will locate the cell with the value you want (let's call that `f`) - then you can use `f.Row` and `f.Column` to get the row and column headers.  Post your current code and you'll get more help.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion on how to achieve your goal. If anything is unclear let me know in the comments.

```
Sub FindAndModify()

    Dim cel As Range
    Dim LookupValue As Double
    Dim intRow As Integer
    Dim intCol As Integer
    Dim celValue As Double

    LookupValue = "0.5" 'Define your Lookup Value here or read it from a cell

    For Each cel In Sheet1.UsedRange

        If cel.Value = LookupValue Then

            intRow = cel.Row
            intCol = cel.Column

            celValue = cel.Value

            celValue = celValue + Sheet1.Cells(intRow, 1).Value
            celValue = celValue + Sheet1.Cells(1, intCol).Value

            MsgBox "Value is " & celValue & " and address is " & cel.Address

            'Do stuff with your values

        End If

    Next cel

End Sub
```